# Cannot Emulate Ionic v1 app to Android Emulator

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, android-emulator

I am developing an ionic app. And I want to emulate it on real Android device. I already downloaded the Android Studio. I plugged my Android device and when I tried to run this command `ionic cordova run android` There's a lot of errors.

Note: I am on Windows 8.1 32bit. JDK 32 bit.

This is for an academic thesis.

This is the error:

[image: This is the error]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already solved my problem! As we can see in the error that I posted, it is the gradle file! It is corrupted download. What I did is delete the `.gradle` folder and run `ionic cordova run adnroid`. In that way, it will automatically download the gradle file! Thanks for the replies by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled usb debugging on your device? You'll have to enable developer mode on your Android. Google can tell you how, but you just go to settings/about/build number,  tap 7 or 8 times... Then, you should be able to use ionic run android --device. That should build out to emulate so long as you've installed the Android sdk.

Comment: What does your package.json file look like?

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by removing platforms, then add again.

```
ionic cordova platform rm android 
ionic cordova platform add android
```

if above solution does not work please run following command,

```
ionic cordova run android --livereload
```

If still problem persist,run same command with --verbose options,

```
ionic cordova run android --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively , and way faster , you can build your app then drag/drop it inside the emulator (running aside)..it will install quicker and run sleeker.
And you'll have peace of mind , I know this is not what you're looking for ,but still a nice hack if you're time-bound.